# asp.net master page missing properties issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have ASP.net page which uses Master page. when I access the DOCUMENT properties I see there is missing properties for Body like BgColor and background. how can I fix this problem?

Screenshots:

[[image: master page properties[1]]
[image: master page source code]

Comment: If you click on "Style" the 3 dots menu appear on the right, and here you can define the styles with a simple UI, but you can create the styles as usual with the css.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. the 3 dots is missing too from style.